# SELECT SUM query with multiple date parameters in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to return information in SQL Server where the values are summed but only where the two of the date parameters are the MAX date.

The table looks something like this:

HH Intervals
[image: HH Intervals]

However I'm trying to sum the values by `SETTLEMENT_DATE` WHERE the `ENTRY_DATE` is the both the MAX `ENTRY_DATE` and MAX `ODS_Load_Date` so I wrote the following query:-

```
SELECT [SETTLEMENT_DAY],
       [COUNTERPARTY_NAME],
       [LINE_ITEM_NAME],
       SUM([VARIABLE_VAL]) AS [PPA>10MW(OP)],
       [STATEMENT_TYPE],
       [ODS_LoadDate]
FROM [ODS].[dbo].[ODS_MM_PPA_FINANCIAL_RESULTS] A
WHERE [LINE_ITEM_NAME] = 'PPA > 10 MW (OP)'
  AND [VARIABLE_NAME] = 'CHARGE_AMOUNT'
  AND [SETTLEMENT_DAY] BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-31'
  AND [COUNTERPARTY_NAME] IN ('IBIL_405145')
  AND [ODS_LoadDate] = (SELECT MAX([ODS_LoadDate])
                        FROM [ODS].[dbo].[ODS_MM_PPA_FINANCIAL_RESULTS] B
                        WHERE A.[SETTLEMENT_DAY] = B.[SETTLEMENT_DAY]
                          AND A.[COUNTERPARTY_NAME] = B.[COUNTERPARTY_NAME]
                          AND A.[LINE_ITEM_NAME] = B.[LINE_ITEM_NAME]
                          AND A.[VARIABLE_VAL] = B.[VARIABLE_VAL]
                          AND A.[STATEMENT_TYPE] = B.[STATEMENT_TYPE]
                          AND A.[STATEMENT_TYPE] = B.[STATEMENT_TYPE]
                          AND A.[VARIABLE_NAME] = B.[VARIABLE_NAME]
                          AND A.[ENTRY_DATE] = B.[ENTRY_DATE]
                          AND A.[ODS_LoadDate] = B.[ODS_LoadDate]
                          AND [ENTRY_DATE] = (SELECT MAX([ENTRY_DATE])
                                              FROM [ODS].[dbo].[ODS_MM_PPA_FINANCIAL_RESULTS] C
                                              WHERE B.[SETTLEMENT_DAY] = C.[SETTLEMENT_DAY]
                                                AND B.[COUNTERPARTY_NAME] = C.[COUNTERPARTY_NAME]
                                                AND B.[LINE_ITEM_NAME] = C.[LINE_ITEM_NAME]
                                                AND B.[VARIABLE_VAL] = C.[VARIABLE_VAL]
                                                AND B.[STATEMENT_TYPE] = C.[STATEMENT_TYPE]
                                                AND B.[STATEMENT_TYPE] = C.[STATEMENT_TYPE]
                                                AND B.[VARIABLE_NAME] = C.[VARIABLE_NAME]
                                                AND B.[ENTRY_DATE] = C.[ENTRY_DATE]
                                                AND B.[ODS_LoadDate] = C.[ODS_LoadDate]))
GROUP BY [SETTLEMENT_DAY],
         [COUNTERPARTY_NAME],
         [LINE_ITEM_NAME],
         [STATEMENT_TYPE],
         [ODS_LoadDate]
ORDER BY [SETTLEMENT_DAY] ASC;
```

However I've found the returned results have both two records for each `SETTLEMENT_DATE` where I only expect to have one which is the MAX `ENTRY_DATE` WHERE the `ODS_Load_Date` is also the MAX `ODS_Load_Date`.

Any ideas how to get past this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you need to check for A.[VARIABLE_VAL] = B.[VARIABLE_VAL] in both subqueries?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Basically i am getting all the records which have the max ods_load_date and max_entry_date in the inner block. After that i sum up and group based on the existing query?

```
SELECT [SETTLEMENT_DAY]
     , [COUNTERPARTY_NAME]
     , [LINE_ITEM_NAME]
     , [STATEMENT_TYPE]
     , [ODS_LoadDate] 
     , SUM([VARIABLE_VAL]) AS [PPA>10MW(OP)]     
  (SELECT
        [SETTLEMENT_DAY],
        [COUNTERPARTY_NAME], 
        [LINE_ITEM_NAME],
        --SUM([VARIABLE_VAL]) AS [PPA>10MW(OP)],
        [STATEMENT_TYPE],
        [ODS_LoadDate],
        [ENTRY_DATE],
        MAX(A.[ODS_LoadDate]) OVER(PARTITION BY [SETTLEMENT_DAY]
                                              ,[COUNTERPARTY_NAME]
                                              ,[LINE_ITEM_NAME]
                                              ,[VARIABLE_VAL]
                                              ,[STATEMENT_TYPE]                                           
                                              ,[VARIABLE_NAME]                                            
                                              ,[ENTRY_DATE]
                                              ,[ODS_LoadDate]
                                              ) as max_ods_load_date
        MAX(A.[ENTRY_DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY [SETTLEMENT_DAY]
                                              ,[COUNTERPARTY_NAME]
                                              ,[LINE_ITEM_NAME]
                                              ,[VARIABLE_VAL]
                                              ,[STATEMENT_TYPE]                                           
                                              ,[VARIABLE_NAME]                                            
                                              ,[ODS_LoadDate]
                                              ,[ENTRY_DATE]
                                              ) as max_entry_date
  FROM [ODS].[dbo].[ODS_MM_PPA_FINANCIAL_RESULTS] AS A
 WHERE [LINE_ITEM_NAME]='PPA > 10 MW (OP)' 
   AND [VARIABLE_NAME]='CHARGE_AMOUNT'
   AND [SETTLEMENT_DAY] BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-31'
   AND [COUNTERPARTY_NAME] IN ('IBIL_405145')    
  )
WHERE x.max_ods_load_date = ods_load_date
  AND x.max_entry_date= x.entry_date  
GROUP BY  [SETTLEMENT_DAY]
        , [COUNTERPARTY_NAME]
        , [LINE_ITEM_NAME]
        , [STATEMENT_TYPE]
        , [ODS_LoadDate]
ORDER BY [SETTLEMENT_DAY] asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You're joining A and B on [ODS_LoadDate], when you want the MAX [ODS_LoadDate], so it's going to include all the rows from both tables. Same for joining B and C on [ENTRY_DATE]. I think if you delete those entries it will work.

For Example, if you have two tables

```
ExampleTable

| Col1 | Col2       |
| 1    | 2018-01-01 |
| 1    | 2018-01-02 |
```

And run:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM ExampleTable a
WHERE Col2 = (SELECT MAX(Col2) FROM ExampleTable b WHERE a.Col1 = b.Col1 AND a.Col2 = b.Col2)
```

You will get:

```
| Col1 | Col2       |
| 1    | 2018-01-01 |
| 1    | 2018-01-02 |
```

When what you want is:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM ExampleTable a
WHERE Col2 = (SELECT MAX(Col2) FROM ExampleTable b WHERE a.Col1 = b.Col1)

| Col1 | Col2       |
| 1    | 2018-01-01 |
```

I think this is what you need (edited to choose MAX([SETTLEMENT_DAY]):

```
SELECT MAX([SETTLEMENT_DAY]),
       [COUNTERPARTY_NAME],
       [LINE_ITEM_NAME],
       SUM([VARIABLE_VAL]) AS [PPA>10MW(OP)],
       [STATEMENT_TYPE],
       [ODS_LoadDate]
FROM [ODS].[dbo].[ODS_MM_PPA_FINANCIAL_RESULTS] A
WHERE [LINE_ITEM_NAME] = 'PPA > 10 MW (OP)'
  AND [VARIABLE_NAME] = 'CHARGE_AMOUNT'
  AND [SETTLEMENT_DAY] BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-31'
  AND [COUNTERPARTY_NAME] IN ('IBIL_405145')
  AND [ODS_LoadDate] = (SELECT MAX([ODS_LoadDate])
                        FROM [ODS].[dbo].[ODS_MM_PPA_FINANCIAL_RESULTS] B
                        WHERE A.[COUNTERPARTY_NAME] = B.[COUNTERPARTY_NAME]
                          AND A.[LINE_ITEM_NAME] = B.[LINE_ITEM_NAME]
                          AND A.[VARIABLE_VAL] = B.[VARIABLE_VAL]
                          AND A.[STATEMENT_TYPE] = B.[STATEMENT_TYPE]
                          AND A.[STATEMENT_TYPE] = B.[STATEMENT_TYPE]
                          AND A.[VARIABLE_NAME] = B.[VARIABLE_NAME]
                          AND A.[ENTRY_DATE] = B.[ENTRY_DATE]
                          AND [ENTRY_DATE] = (SELECT MAX([ENTRY_DATE])
                                              FROM [ODS].[dbo].[ODS_MM_PPA_FINANCIAL_RESULTS] C
                                              WHERE B.[COUNTERPARTY_NAME] = C.[COUNTERPARTY_NAME]
                                                AND B.[LINE_ITEM_NAME] = C.[LINE_ITEM_NAME]
                                                AND B.[VARIABLE_VAL] = C.[VARIABLE_VAL]
                                                AND B.[STATEMENT_TYPE] = C.[STATEMENT_TYPE]
                                                AND B.[STATEMENT_TYPE] = C.[STATEMENT_TYPE]
                                                AND B.[VARIABLE_NAME] = C.[VARIABLE_NAME]))
GROUP BY [COUNTERPARTY_NAME],
         [LINE_ITEM_NAME],
         [STATEMENT_TYPE],
         [ODS_LoadDate]
ORDER BY [SETTLEMENT_DAY] ASC;
```

Comment: Perfect, much appreciated.

Comment: I noticed however when I ran the above that there are still some double entries returned, for example I can see on 6th October I have two records for one of the counterparties, one has an ODS_Load_Date of 2018-11-07 17:23:04.000 and the other 2018-11-07 10:59:05.000?

Comment: Do they have different SETTLEMENT_DAY values? I imagine it's something in the group by clause that's causing the duplication. Could you knock up some sample data?

Comment: Hi Anthony, they do have different SETTLEMENT_DAY values yeah, I'll get some sample data in a bit and upload.

Comment: Then you probably want to put a MAX(SETTLEMENT_DAY) in your initial select and remove SETTLEMENT_DAY from the group by. I've updated my answer to reflect that.